# Facet count in Azure cognitive search (Automagic)

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have created a Azure cognitive search App preview from Azure portal.
How can I change the facet count value using "Automagic" in Azure cognitive search. By default the facet count is 5.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the JS code for this sample app does not allow you to change the facet count.  Normally, you can just send a request to Azure Cognitive Search with something like facet=foo,count:X where X is the count you need, but this functionality has not been added to this demo search app you are referring to.